# Creating a sentence based on the values in a data frame

Tags: r

I want to create a sentence based on the values in a data frame. I have the following data.frame:

```
canada <- c(50, 50, 50)
korea <- c(70, 70, 70)
brazil <- c(100, 100, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")

fruit
>        apple orange banana
> canada    50     50     50
> korea     70     70     70
> brazil   100    100    100
```

When I type **canada**, want the output to look like this:

```
canada
Canada consumes average number of apples, average number of oranges, 
and average number of bananas.
```

So, I tried the following:

```
average <- 'average number of '
if(fruit$'apple' > 90)
{
  cat("Canada", 
          average, fruit$'apple', 
          average, fruit$'orange',
          "and ", average, fruit$'banana'
      )
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work, and I am stuck here. Can someone guide me to the right path? I will put in the work to learn!

Comment: For starters you can't use `$` with a `matrix` like your `fruit`

Comment: Thanks. It has been some time since I touched R. I'm confident that I can recollect the basics. Would you mind providing me with a scaffolding?

Comment: You can access matrix columns like `fruit[,"apple"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt, assuming that you may have columns other than apple / orange / banana, but you'd always want all the values in a given row.

```
myfun <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]

  phrase <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                   function(x, n, i) {paste0("consumes average ", x[i], " of ", n[i], "s")}, # "s" added assuming there's always a plural number of fruits
                   x=myrow, n=names(myrow))
  phrase[length(phrase)] <- paste0("and ", phrase[length(phrase)], ".")
  phrase <- paste(phrase, collapse = ", ")

  cat(tools::toTitleCase(val), phrase)
}

> myfun("KOREA")
Korea consumes average 70 of apples, consumes average 70 of oranges, and consumes average 70 of bananas.
> myfun("canada")
Canada consumes average 50 of apples, consumes average 50 of oranges, and consumes average 50 of bananas.
> myfun("braZIL")
Brazil consumes average 100 of apples, consumes average 100 of oranges, and consumes average 100 of bananas.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something Like this?

```
canada <- c(50, 50, 50)
korea <- c(70, 70, 70)
brazil <- c(100, 100, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")

CA<-fruit[1,1]
CO<-fruit[1,2]
CB<-fruit[1,3]

Canada<-paste("Canada on average eats",CA,"apples",CO,"oranges 
and",CB,"bananas")

>Canada
[1] "Canada on average eats 50 apples 50 oranges and 50 bananas"
```

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly what I was thinking, but I really appreciate the response : )